# How to print content fit to defined paper size?

Tags: html, css, printing

How to print nicely while the content show in div fit to each page without any extra blank page?

```
 @page {
        width: 1.97in;
        height: 1.57in;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
.label{
        padding: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 1.97in;
        height: 1.57in;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-top: 1px dotted;
        page-break-after: always;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    }
```

This is my label printer setting
[image]

I want to print the content as label sticker, but it always show extra blank when  printing. How can i configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit media print

```
@page {
    width: 1.97in;
    height: 1.57in;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@media print {
    html, body {
        width: 1.97in;
        height: 1.97in;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not printing in A4 size paper, it's some sort like a label sticker size